# Dexguard as a public Maven dependency

Tags: android, gradle, obfuscation, dexguard

Is there any reason Dexguard is not available on any public maven repo? Maven Central, JCenter or even anything hosted directly by Guardsquare would work. So far I have seen it distributed only as a zipped bunch of jars. Why?

Comment: Maybe because it is paid ?

Comment: True, it is paid, but as far as I know you still cannot use it without a license file, which is linked to your app's package id.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question does not belong on stackoverflow. It should be obvious why a commercial product is not available to the public, especially in the security oriented world.

Comment: I agree, that it could be not the best place to ask the question, but I do not see a better one so far. I do believe though, that keeping the obfuscated binaries of paid security software helps to perceive it as something more secure and robust. As I mentioned before, you still have to purchase the license to use it and as long as they are obfuscated, there is no harm in it. 2Moderators: feel free to close the question if you feel it is inappropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the answer: As of version 8.5, DexGuard is accessible via secure Maven repository.

Please see the page Integration / Gradle plugin / Maven repository in the manual for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that many commercial products are available on a public repo so it is no surprise that DexGuard is only distributed to customers with a valid license.

Comment: Hi Thomas, good to hear from you. I understand your point, but as I mentioned above, as long as there is no way to use the product without a valid license, what is the point to hide it? Security through obscurity? Lots of companies are following this pattern, but it simply means, that every user of a product like that have to either drop it in as jar dependency or deploy it on their own artifactory/nexus/etc or even make a new artifactory/nexus/etc just specifically for dexguard. I am just saying, that it raises operations costs for thousands of projects. Maybe there is a way to fix that?

Comment: Most users don't update their version on a regular basis and there is no need to have it in your own repository. Simply add a flatDir repo and it should work without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like DexGuard introduces "Secured Maven Repo" see https://www.guardsquare.com/blog/dexguard-85-released

How to use it - see https://www.antit.io/tech-blog/tutorial-dexguard-android-and-react-native.
But you would need credentials = meaning pay for it.